# Android Spinner set item that is selected on start

Tags: android, spinner

i Have a Spinner on my activity that contains a list of String, it is declared like this:

```
String[] notificationStatus = new String[statuses.size()];
        for (int i =0; i<statuses.size();i++){
            notificationStatus[i]=statuses.get(i);
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String> (
                this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, notificationStatus );

        aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(aa);
        spinner.setPrompt(getString(R.string.chooseType));
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                posType=position;
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                // your code here
            }

            });
```

Now when i start this activity i got first item of notificationStatus Array on the button (possition 0 at spinner), is there a way to start a activity and put for example 3rd item of the array at the possition of 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually i have found out how to do this.
First i create a list from the array:

```
List<String> statusCheck = new ArrayList<String>();
        statusCheck = Arrays.asList(notificationStatus);
```

Next i check where on the list is String i am looking for and put set selection on it:

```
spinner2.setSelection(statusCheck.indexOf(status));
```

Comment: when do you set the adapter? after or before setselection?